# Why does ruby define variables even if it never executes the variable assignment code?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

Given the following code:

```
a = true # let's assign `a` a value

# and let's test if calling `b`, an unassigned variable, throws an error
begin
  puts "The value of b is: #{b.inspect}"
rescue NameError => e
  puts "Caught an error: #{e}"
end

a || b = true # the assignment should never be executed because `a` is `true`

puts "The value of b is: #{b.inspect}" # will calling `b` still raise an error?
```

We get the following result:

```
Caught an error: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
The value of b is: nil
```

Even though we expected calling `b` to raise an error the second time, we see that `b` is now, in fact, `nil`.

Why is that? Why does `b` get assigned `nil`? Since the `||` never reached the assignment, I would expect `b` to remain undefined. How can it be defined, but not assigned a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) explain how variables are created; the explanation as I understand it is that's just how the parser works:

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:

```
a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
p local_variables # prints [:a]
p a # prints nil
```

You can see other examples of this:

```
b = true if false # b is nil
"test" || c = true # c is nil
```

And others it doesn't get assigned:

```
puts d if false # d generates a NameError
```